# Send object to method

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist

I write the following snippet but for some reason it does not work :

**Main:**

```
    TestClasss testClass = new TestClass;

    ArrayList<TestObject> listObj = new ArrayList<>();
    TestObject tb = new TestObject();
    tb.setName("asd");
    tb.setId("13");
    listObj.add(tb);

    testClass.addValue(listObj );
```

**TestClasss**

```
 public void addValalue(ArrayList<Object> list) {
        Log.e("list size is", String.valueOf(list.size()));
    }
```

I have an error on the following line `testClass.addValue(listObj )` :

```
Error:(47, 11) error: method addValalue in class TestClasss cannot be applied to given types;
required: ArrayList<Object>
found: ArrayList<TestObject>
reason: actual argument ArrayList<TestObject> cannot be converted to ArrayList<Object> by method invocation conversion
```

I tried to create a class `DataObject` :

```
public class DataObject {
}
```

and extend this class `TestObject`:

```
public class TestObject extends DataObject
```

and change method `addValue` like this:

```
public void addValalue(ArrayList<DataObject> list) {
     Log.e("list size is", String.valueOf(list.size()));
}
```

but still have the same error

Comment: Change  
`public void addValalue(ArrayList<Object> list)` 
to `public void addValalue(ArrayList<TestObject> list) `

Comment: @AhmedAbidi thanks for answer. But if i want sent this method not only `TestObject`

Answer (score 3):

Either change:

```
public void addValalue(ArrayList<Object> list)
```

to:

```
public void addValalue(ArrayList<? extends Object> list)
```

BTW "Valalue" is not a word in the dictionary (just making sure you haven't confused it with "Value")

Comment: wow!! this line `public void addValalue(ArrayList<? extends Object> list)` what I need. Thanks a lot